# Do I use a SwingWorker?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, stopwatch

While my code sends http calls I want it to alter the `JLabel` on a window (basically showing approximately how much time is left before the http calls end). I have been looking into `SwingWorkers` due to another question I asked here, but I'm not sure how I use it. The code I am writing basically has a loop to send the calls, each time timing how long it takes to run the call, calculates the approximate time left and then sends this to the `JLabel` (NB the JLabel is in a different instantiated object).

Most `SwingWorker` examples show a function continuing in the background that is not affected by the worker thread (e.g. a counter based entirely on time rather than being altered by the code). If this is the case then isn't the alteration of the `JLabel` just part of the worker thread as it the code runs through new loop -> calculate time & make call -> alter `JLabel`? I'm probably wrong but then how do I have the JLabel altered by the code rather than a independent thread?

One of my issues was that when I initially set my code up there was nothing changing in the `JLabel`.

Here is my code:

```java
package transcription.windows;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class PleaseWaitWindow {

    private JLabel pleaseWaitJLabel = new JLabel("Please wait");
    private GridBagConstraints containerGbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    private Container contentPaneContainer = new Container();
    private JFrame pleaseWaitJFrame;

    public JLabel getPleaseWaitJLabel() {
        return pleaseWaitJLabel;
    }

    public JFrame setPleaseWaitWindow() {
        pleaseWaitJFrame = new JFrame();
        contentPaneContainer = setContentPane();
        pleaseWaitJFrame.setContentPane(contentPaneContainer);
        pleaseWaitJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pleaseWaitJFrame.setTitle("");
        pleaseWaitJFrame.setSize(350, 150);
        pleaseWaitJFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pleaseWaitJFrame.setVisible(true);

        return pleaseWaitJFrame;
    }

    private Container setContentPane() {
        containerGbc.insets.bottom = 1;
        containerGbc.insets.top = 2;
        containerGbc.insets.right = 1;
        containerGbc.insets.left = 1;
        containerGbc.weightx = 1;
        containerGbc.weighty = 1;

        contentPaneContainer.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        contentPaneContainer.setSize(800, 700);
        setPleaseWaitJLabel();

        return contentPaneContainer;
    }

    private void setPleaseWaitJLabel() {
        containerGbc.gridx = 2;
        containerGbc.gridy = 5;
        containerGbc.gridwidth = 2;
        containerGbc.gridheight = 1;
        contentPaneContainer.add(pleaseWaitJLabel, containerGbc);
    }

    public void setJLabelDisplay(String displayTime) {
        pleaseWaitJLabel.setText(displayTime);
    }

    public void closeWindow() {
        pleaseWaitJFrame.dispose();
    }
    }
```

Method that is part of the ServiceUpload class:

```java
    public String cuttingLoop(String mpBase64Piece, String jobName, String email) {
        Integer numberOfPiecesMinusEnd = (int) Math.ceil(mpBase64Piece.length() / 500000.0);
        List<String> base64List = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPiecesMinusEnd; i++) {

            if (mpBase64Piece.length() >= 500000) {
                base64List.add(mpBase64Piece.substring(0, 500000));
                mpBase64Piece = mpBase64Piece.substring(500000);
            }

        }
        base64List.add(mpBase64Piece);

        pleaseWaitWindow = new PleaseWaitWindow();
        pleaseWaitWindow.setPleaseWaitWindow();
        for (int n = 0; n < base64List.size(); n++) {
            numberOfLoopsLeft = numberOfPiecesMinusEnd - n;
            Stopwatch stopwatch = null;
            String tag;
            Stopwatch.createStarted();
            if (base64List.get(n) != null) {
                if (n == 0) {
                    tag = "start";
                } else if (n == base64List.size() - 1) {
                    tag = "end";
                } else {
                    tag = "middle";
                }
                stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
                response = providerUpload.executeUploadHttp(base64List.get(n), jobName, tag, email);
                stopwatch.stop();
            }
            long oneLoopTime = stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            pleaseWaitWindow.setJLabelDisplay(numberOfLoopsLeft*oneLoopTime+" seconds remaining");
            LOGGER.info("complete");
        }
        pleaseWaitWindow.closeWindow();
        return response;
    }
```

One of my issues was the code did not show the 'JLabel' when a 'SwingWorker' isn't used with the above code.

Comment: It's not clear how you even try to use the `SwingWorker` from this code.

Comment: That's what I thought @daniu but someone in my last quest closed it saying a SwingWorker had to be used and that was already asked about. How do I get the JLabel to change?

Comment: *in my last quest closed it saying a SwingWorker had to be used* - the suggestion was to use a `Swing Timer` or a `SwingWorker`. The `Swing Tutorial` has more information on both suggestions. Read the section on "How to Use a Swing Timer" and "Concurrency in Swing" especially the section on "Tasks That Have Interim Results".

Comment: Would I be able to use a swing timer as the event triggering the swing worker is not based on a constant 'timer' but on the length of time it takes to send the http?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best you split up your code into areas of responsibilities. Let's go with three: 1. the worker (ie the upload); 2. the display (ie the JLabel update); 3. integration of the two (the first two are independent of each other, so you'll need something to tie them together).

Abstracting from the actual work, you can use standard interfaces. The first one is just a `Runnable`, ie not taking any parameters and not returning anything. The second one is a `Consumer<String>` because it takes a `String` (to display) but doesn't return anything. The third will be your main control.

Let's start with the control because that's simple:

```
Consumer<String> display = createDisplay();
Runnable worker = createWorker();
CompletableFuture.runAsync(worker);
```

This will start the worker in a separate Thread which is what it sounds like you want.

So here's your uploader:

```
Consumer<String> display = // tbd, see below
Runnable worker = () -> {
    String[] progress = {"start", "middle", "finish"};
    for (String pr : progress) {
        display.accept(pr);
        Thread.sleep(1000); // insert your code here
    }
}
```

Note that this worker actually does depend on the consumer; that is somewhat "unclean", but will do.

Now for the display. Having defined it as a `Consumer<String>`, it's abstract enough that we can just print the progress on the console.

```
Consumer<String> display = s -> System.out.printf("upload status: %s%n", s);
```

You however want to update a `JLabel`; so the consumer would look like

```
Consumer<String> display = s -> label.setText(s);
// for your code
s -> pleaseWaitWindow.getPleaseWaitLabel().setText(s);
```

*Your actual question*

So if you do that, you will notice that your label text doesn't get updated as you expect. That is because the `label.setText(s)` gets executed in the thread in which the worker is running; it needs to be inserted in the Swing thread. That's where the `SwingWorker` comes in.

The `SwingWorker` has a `progress` field which is what you can use for your labels; it also has a `doInBackground()` which is your actual upload worker thread. So you end up with

```
class UploadSwingWorker {
    public void doInBackground() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            setProgress(i);
            Thread.sleep(1000); // again, your upload code
        }
    }
}
```

So how does that update your label? The `setProgress` raises a `PropertyChangeEvent` you can intercept; this done using a `PropertyChangeListener` with the signature

```
void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
```

This is a functional interface, so you can implement this with a lambda, in your case

```
String[] displays = {"start", "middle", "finish"};
updateLabelListener = e -> {
    int index = ((Integer) e.getNewValue()).intValue(); // the progress you set
    String value = displays[index];
    label.setText(value);
}
```

and you can add it to the `SwingWorker` using

```
SwingWorker uploadWorker = new UploadSwingWorker();
uploadWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(updateLabelListener);
uploadWorker.execute(); // actually start the worker
```

*Simpler*

Note that I myself have never used a `SwingWorker` this way. The much simpler way to get around the problem that the GUI is not updated from within your worker thread is to call the GUI update using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

Coming back to the initial `Consumer<String>` I brought up, you can do

```
    Consumer<String> display = s -> SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        () -> pleaseWaitWindow.getPleaseWaitLabel().setText(s)
    );
```

and that should do. This allows you to keep your worker in the more abstract `Runnable` and use the usual scheduling mechanisms to run it (`ExecutorService.submit()` or `CompletableFuture.runAsync()` for example), while still allowing to update the GUI on a similarly simple level.

Comment: Fantastic answer @daniu. I'll try and get my head around it! First time I've taken these new steps into what seems a very complex world of threads! One question though. The 'start, middle, end' isn't the value to be displayed on the jLabel, I need to put on the length of time it took to do the http call (in the executeHttpCall method). I know how to calculate the time  but am I still able to send the int just as you have sent the string array?

Comment: @HywelGriffiths I added another way of doing it that I actually prefer because it's simpler and not bound to the Swing concept as closely.